# Jmeter not showing JSON response for GraphQL query

Tags: json, jmeter, graphql

View Results tree is showing green 302 and saying there is a response, but jmeter isn't displaying it. I don't have follow redirects or save response as MD5 hash enabled. I've followed another example of a basic query and that seems to be working, so I'm guessing there is something potentially wrong with my query.

[image]

`{"query":"lookup(lookupId:""TH53158""){data}"}`

I've read that the escape key for quotes in jmeter is "" for queries, but haven't seen any other examples of it. How can I fix up jmeter to get a good json response?

Answer (score 0):

What method? [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) or [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)?

1. In case of [GET](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#get-request) you need to pass your request using `query` URL parameter like:

   [image]
2. In  case of [POST](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) you need to pass your request using "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

   [image]

   in addition you will need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header:

   [image]

More information: [GraphQL - Serving over HTTP](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/)

Comment: Yeah that's the format I followed on another thread for Graphql POST. It turns out that my query `"lookup(lookupId:""TH53158""){data}"` needed two changes. `\"` is the escape for quotes inside quotes and it needed another set of brackets, I'm guessing since it had parenthesis. The working query looks like `"{ lookup(lookupId:\"TH53158\"){data} }" `